# New Google Play Services API, Holding connection through activities

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I am currently working on adapting an existing android game with the "old google play games" services to the new API, as I updated the library and found all deprecated methods to be erased.

In the previous implementation we used a singleton-like approach of the "GameHelper" which allowed us to keep connection across multiple activities instead of reconnecting them all the time. Our only issue with this was getting the "Error Resolution" debug messages displayed, but we handled this with some modifications inside the GameHelper itself (e.g. setting a new errorresolution activity, every time we switch activity instead of always setting up the whole connection). **This is the first thing which doesnt seem to work for the new GameHelper mechanics.**

But the second issue we already experienced in the previous version of the api was displaying when an achievement got unlocked or similiar. This was solved by reinitializing the actual GamesClient. **But in the new version, this is not possible anymore.** So my question: How are you handling multiple activities?  are you simply reconnecting everytime?

I'd love to hear your opinion.

edit: How bad is reconnecting on an activity switch?
The thing is.. there is like 3 activites an following usage flow. TrackSelectionActivity -> GameActivity -> GameSummaryActivity ... repeat. 
Are these actual internet connections or just locally to the play services client?

Comment: I have never used GPS myself but your problem seems to come from trying to force a service-oriented object into an activity. Try cleaning things up and going for a service instead.

Comment: I like your point, but thats not the way GPS work. They are using activities for handling the initializiations which then get used for displaying all kind of popups (achievements, login messages ,..) to the user... The thing is just... if the object is always initialized (which would be possible without a problem in a service, or just in the application class as a singleton), you can't reset the activity, which gets used for user interaction, anymore.